# Identifying java file with out Javadoc

Tags: java, regex, javadoc

I would like to parse .java files which does NOT contain description about the class.

I am trying it to do with perl, but not able to get the approprate regexp to parse the following pattern

```
/**
 * Some text describing about the class
 *
 */
```

For example:

```
Class CommunicationServer {
...
}
```

The description of class is missing.
What regexp can be used in perl to parse this type of pattern?

Here is the what I tried but it does not work

```
while ( valid file handle) {
    my $isLine = $_;
    chomp($isLine);
    if ($isLine =~ m/^(\/\*\\*)/) {
        #if ($isLine =~ /[^\W]/) {  # Any non-word character.
        print $isLine ".\n";
    }
}
```

Or are you aware of any tool which help me to identify the non document class such as above?

Many thanks for input.

Comment: Any reason why you're trying to do this in Perl rather than (say) using checkstyle? http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html

Comment: Are you aware of the `..` and `...` operators?

Comment: The aim is to list all the Java classes without document. So with perl script I iterate over the package, open the file and tried to parse the comment. With checkstlye in place I have to open each of the Java file and inspect. There are over 1k classes.

Answer (score 1):

`(/\\*\\*.*?\\*/[^;]*?class[^{]*)\\{`

This thing can capture one class definition with a javadoc from a file. In case you don't have nested classes with javadoc and don't want to check them, you can use it. If this regex fails then your file does not have a class javadoc.

Make sure that your `\s` and `.` eat newline.

This may not always work. Did not test it much. Comment and I will answer.